# Split by Regex pattern containing zero or even number of punctuation characters java

Tags: java, regex, split, punctuation

In java,I need to split a sentence by '(single quote)  and sentence contains punctuation characters like ?,^ or !

The sentence gets splitted only If the sentence contains zero or even of punctuation characters,otherwise it will not split,

Note:

I need in regex pattern with split logic only thats my requirement

For example

```
ABC??'DEF?'GHI'JKL????'MNO'
```

Output needed...

```
ABC??
DEF?'GHI            //here sentence contains single or odd no of punctuation(?) char, so it wont split by single quote '
JKL????
MNO
```

I need a relevant regex pattern in java,please suggest a solution

Comment: And the code that you tried to achieve this?

Comment: My solution is simple, search a solution then ask for help on that solution. The pattern is not really hard but I would not try to check "even" punctuation with a regex

Comment: I get the feeling that maybe you will need a primitive parser here.  Regex alone may not be enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most efficient, but this is quite simple to understand

First, simply split on the `'` to get an array of `String`.

Then, for each `String`, check the amount of character that you want to be even :

```
array[i].replaceAll("[^?']", "").length() % 2
// 0 = even
// 1 = odd
```

Based on that, if the result is odd, concatenate the current cell to the next one

```
array[i+1] = array[i] + array[i+1];
```

Then clear the current cell, since the value have been added for the next check.

```
array[i] = null;
```

You will need to clear those null at the end of course. This allow you to rebuild the `String` for the next iteration.

Code:

```
    String tmp = "ABC?'DEF?'GHI'JKL????'MNO'";
    String[] split = tmp.split("'");

    //don't check the last, because we can't do much for it
    for(int i = 0 ; i < split.length - 1; i++) { 
        //Odd amount of ?'
        if(split[i].replaceAll("[^?']", "").length() % 2 > 0) { 
            //concat with the next item
            split[i + 1] = split[i] + "'" + split[i + 1]; 
            //remove current
            split[i] = null; 
        }
    }

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(split));
    list.removeIf(s -> s == null);

    System.out.println("Result:");
    for(String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

> "ABC?'DEF?'GHI'JKL????'MNO'"

```
ABC?'DEF?'GHI
JKL????
MNO
```

> "ABC??'DEF?'GHI'JKL????'MNO'"

```
ABC??
DEF?'GHI
JKL????
MNO
```

Note that we could work with a `List` the all time, or even a `Stream`, but the `Collection` is not really the point here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
String s = "ABC??'DEF?'GHI'JKL????'MNO'";
String[] split = s.split("'");
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    System.out.println(split[i]);
```

Comment: This won't generate `DEF?'GHI` for the second line, since your solution would consume every `'`.

Comment: I doubt the output will be the one in the question. You are not check if the "sub sentence" have odd amount of punctuation.

Comment: This solution is inappropriate as it does not  split by checking zero or even of punctuation characters,that's more important,also i need it in regex pattern only..Please suggest appropriate answer